# How to scrape a website that render data with JavaScript

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping this website https://robertsspaceindustries.com/pledge/ship-upgrades?to-ship=173 i want to get the 'Arrow' text on the right side of the 'choose your ship' text

I have tried using requests and BeautifulSoup to select the tag that contains the text, when i inspect the page i can see where the text is it's between the  tag i try selecting it with soup.select(".name") i still get empty string, might be the data is being rendered with Javascript so i tried selenium and try to wait for the element to load before selecting it, still nothing here's my code

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "name"))
    )

    select_tags = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".name")
    for tag in select_tags:
        print(tag.text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Arrow

Comment: Did you use `driver.maximize_window()` or preconditions for running browser in maximized state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium might be overkill for a task like this where you don't need to interact with the page. This is just a few lines with [`requests_html`](https://html.python-requests.org/):

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://robertsspaceindustries.com/pledge/ship-upgrades?to-ship=173'

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
print(r.html.find('.info > .name', first=True).text)
```

which produces `Arrow` as expected.

For this particular site you may also check elsewhere in the content to get the information you want without JavaScript support required, for example:

```py
import json

import requests

url = 'https://robertsspaceindustries.com/pledge/ship-upgrades?to-ship=173'

r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text

json_start_text = 'fromShips: '
json_start = text.index(json_start_text) + len(json_start_text)
json_end = text.index(']', json_start)
json_text = text[json_start:json_end + 1]
data = json.loads(json_text)
for ship in data:
    name = ship['name']
    msrp = ship['msrp']
    print(f'{name} {msrp}')
```

which results in

```
Aurora ES $20.00
P52 Merlin $20.00
Aurora MR $25.00
P72 Archimedes $30.00
Mustang Alpha $30.00
Aurora LX $30.00
...
Arrow $75.00
...
```